# MinGW compilation "file not recognized: File format not recognized"

Tags: gcc, makefile, cygwin, mingw

I'm trying to compile a c++ program and I am having some issues. In particular, when I use x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc as my compiler, it complains half way through my compilation saying "tmp/src/libfastms/solver/solver.cpp.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized".

Here is my makefile (not mine, I'm trying to adapt this makefile to a cygwin environment) https://pastebin.com/vgnVYJUL

Here is the console output when I run make:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -o tmp/src/libfastms/solver/solver.cpp.o src/libfastms/solver/solver.cpp  -Wall -O3 -m64  -Isrc/libfastms  -DDISABLE_OPENMP -DDISABLE_OPENCV -DDISABLE_CUDA
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -o tmp/src/libfastms/solver/solver_base.cpp.o src/libfastms/solver/solver_base.cpp  -Wall -O3 -m64  -Isrc/libfastms  -DDISABLE_OPENMP -DDISABLE_OPENCV -DDISABLE_CUDA
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -o tmp/src/libfastms/solver/solver_host.cpp.o src/libfastms/solver/solver_host.cpp  -Wall -O3 -m64  -Isrc/libfastms  -DDISABLE_OPENMP -DDISABLE_OPENCV -DDISABLE_CUDA
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -o tmp/src/libfastms/util/has_cuda.cpp.o src/libfastms/util/has_cuda.cpp  -Wall -O3 -m64  -Isrc/libfastms  -DDISABLE_OPENMP -DDISABLE_OPENCV -DDISABLE_CUDA
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -o tmp/src/libfastms/util/image_mat.cpp.o src/libfastms/util/image_mat.cpp  -Wall -O3 -m64  -Isrc/libfastms  -DDISABLE_OPENMP -DDISABLE_OPENCV -DDISABLE_CUDA
ld -r -o tmp/src/libfastms/libfastms.o tmp/src/libfastms/solver/solver.cpp.o tmp/src/libfastms/solver/solver_base.cpp.o tmp/src/libfastms/solver/solver_host.cpp.o tmp/src/libfastms/util/has_cuda.cpp.o tmp/src/libfastms/util/image_mat.cpp.o
tmp/src/libfastms/solver/solver.cpp.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
Makefile:167: recipe for target 'tmp/src/libfastms/libfastms.o' failed
make: *** [tmp/src/libfastms/libfastms.o] Error 1
```

Some other notes:

- I don't have this problem when I compile with g++ (only seems to be minGW)
- A common solution to this problem is to clean the directory of residual object files. This does not work.
- Another common reason for this is trying to compile .h files. Obviously I am not doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with building on Windows, however I suspect your issue is that the linker is trying to link a 32bit program, and you're giving it 64bit object files.  Why are you using `ld` directly to link your program?  Why don't you use `x86_65-w64-mingw32-gcc` as a front-end for the linker?  That's the traditional way to link things and it almost always works better since the compiler front-end knows what special extra options to hand to the linker.  Does the `-shared` option work on minGW?  If you must use `ld` you'll probably need to find out how to tell it to use 64bit objects.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. As I mentioned, I'm modifying someone else's makefile in order to compile this program for windows. Instead of using ld how would I approach the problem? Would I just call x86_65-w64-mingw32-gcc -o <all previously generated object files> ? Also, excuse my lack of experience, from what i understand, x86_65-w64-mingw32-gcc is a 64 bit compiler so why would it try to link a 32 bit program?

Comment: 64bit compilers can usually generate both 32bit and 64bit code.  32bit Intel is basically a subset of 64bit.  For whatever reason it's been traditional on Windows for compilers to generate 32bit code by default unless otherwise specified.  So, a raw `ld` command will expect to generate 32bits.  As for your other question, Mike Kinghan has provided details in his answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are compiling your object files with a 64-bit compiler driver, `w64-mingw32-gcc`,
and with `-m64` you are explicitly directing it to generate 64-bit code (unnecessarily,
as that is its default). But you are linking with a 32-bit linker that does not
understand 64-bit object files.

This is happening because in your makefile you are, unusually, invoking `ld`
explicitly for your incremental `solver` linkage:

```
COMMAND_LINK_SOLVER=ld -r -o $@ $^
```

rather than delegating linkage to your compiler driver in the usual way, and
a 32-bit `ld` from a different toolchain is being found in your `PATH` before
the 64-bit one belonging to your `mingw-w64` toolchain.

To avoid this, invoke the linker via the compiler driver as normal, which for your
`solver` linkage means:

```
COMMAND_LINK_SOLVER=$(GXX) -Wl,-r -o $@ $^
```

You can depend on `w64-mingw32-gcc` to invoke the `ld` that was installed with it.

There is no need to correct your `main` linkage as it is already done the right way.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. It now seems to get past that step. However, it seems the main linkage is complaining.

x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o main tmp/src/examples/example_batchprocessing.cpp.o tmp/src/examples/example_gui.cpp.o tmp/src/examples/main.cpp.o tmp/src/libfastms/libfastms.o
tmp/src/libfastms/libfastms.o: In function `WinMainCRTStartup':
/usr/src/debug/mingw64-x86_64-runtime-5.0.2-1/crt/crtexe.c:171: multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup' . After googling this error, it seems that a lot of people have that error when they dont add the -c flag to compile .cpp files. Not the case here

Comment: @AlexKyriazis Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).
If you now have another problem that you cannot solve yourself, you can ask
a new question.