# Why doesn't MinGW's linker recognise libgslcblas.dll.a?

Tags: makefile, g++, mingw, linker-errors

Solution: I can now include libgsl and libgslcblas when I compile minimal code in the /home/HORTICULTIST location in cygwin's directory. Before I set the environment variables in Windows when I should've used `export` in cygwin's interface.

I'm trying to compile a C/C++ library from github which depends on GSL, using MinGW version 9.2.0 and Cygwin, but we get the error below. I'm unfamiliar with makefiles, and the [relevant Stack Overflow sugestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44477951/mingw-compilation-file-not-recognized-file-format-not-recognized) isn't magically fixing the issue in this case.

**The error:**

```
C:/cygwin64/lib/libgslcblas.dll.a: file not recognized: file format not recognized
```

**The makefile:**

```
CC = g++
LDFLAGS = -lgsl -lm -lgslcblas 

LSOURCE = main.cpp corpus.cpp slda.cpp utils.cpp opt.cpp
LHEADER = corpus.h slda.h utils.h opt.h settings.h

slda: $(LSOURCE) $(HEADER)
      $(CC) $(LSOURCE) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:  -rm -f *.o slda
```

What needs to change?

Thanks~

Comment: Generally speaking, Cygwin and MinGW and *alternatives*, not complements.  I suggest choosing **one** for any given project.

Comment: Thanks - I'll rethink how I'm trying to do this. I installed Cygwin as a 'convenient' way of installing GSL, but that was almost definitely misguided when I already had MinGW.